# Problemas con paginacion con post type WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Intento paginar los post de un post type, e copiado el código de otra web donde lo usé pero por alguna razón que no logro comprender no consigo que funcione.

No me salen los textos de los botones de siguiente y anterior. Y cuando le das a cualquier botón no hace nada

```
<?php
  $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'libros',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
  );

  $the_query = null;
  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

  if($the_query->have_posts()){ 
?>

    <section class="container libros-home">
        <div class="row justify-content-sm-between libros-destacados-autor" style="margin:2%;">

        <?php
            while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
        ?>  

                        <div class="card col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 card-destacado" align="center">
                            <div class="autor-imatge">
                                <div class="rodona gran">
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" title="Santiago Posteguillo" itemprop="author"><img src="<?php echo get_field("portada")["url"] ?>" class="photo " itemprop="image"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="autor-info">
                                <span class="nom"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" title="Santiago Posteguillo" itemprop="author"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

        <?php
            endwhile;
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-12 options border-bottom">
                <div class="container"> 
                    <div id="main">
                        <!-- pagination -->
                        <ul class="pagination">
                        <div>
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <span class="page-link"><?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Anterior'); ?></span>
                            </li>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <span class="page-link"><?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Siguiente', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></span>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php 
    }
    wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Espero que podáis ayudarme, porque entre esto y el problema que tengo para filtrar estoy que me subo por las paredes.